# How do you update async pipe data/state after CRUD operations?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is a simple example. I have an observable `users$` that stores users fetched from an API. I also have another observable `usersWithAction$` that encapsulates state using `scan` operator when CRUD actions happen.

I have a question about my `usersWithAction$` observable. Even though my approach using `merge` operator works correctly, I feel like this solution is hacky and there must be a better way of doing it. I'd appreciate any suggestions or links to relevant info. Thanks.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qwuke8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)

Here is *data.service.ts*:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
}

type ActionDelete = { action: 'delete'; id: number };
type ActionAdd = { action: 'add'; user: User };

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private actionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<'' | ActionAdd | ActionDelete>(
    ''
  );
  action$ = this.actionSubject.asObservable();

  users$ = this.http
    .get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .pipe(shareReplay(1));

  usersWithAction$ = merge(this.action$, this.users$).pipe(
    scan((acc, value) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) return [...value];
      else {
        if (value && value.action === 'delete') {
          return acc.filter((user) => user.id !== value.id);
        }
        if (value && value.action === 'add') {
          return [...acc, value.user];
        }
      }
    }, []),
    tap((data) => console.log(data, 'data')),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  deleteUser(id: number) {
    // Do some API related requests
    this.actionSubject.next({ action: 'delete', id: id });
  }

  addUser() {
    // Do some API related requests
    this.actionSubject.next({
      action: 'add',
      user: { id: 123, name: 'John Doe', phone: '234234' },
    });
  }
}
```

Here *is app.component.ts*:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  users$ = this.dataService.usersWithAction$;

  deleteUser(id: number) {
    this.dataService.deleteUser(id);
  }

  addUser() {
    this.dataService.addUser()
  }
}
```

Here is *app.component.html*:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users$ | async" class="user-container">
  <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ user.phone }}</p>
  <button type="button" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</button>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="addUser()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Looks elegant to me, go for it, you don't need both the `shareReplay` I guess!

Comment: I would store the users list in the service itself (this service is a store) and would use 4 different effects for CRUD operations. Is there any reason to stick with Angular 15?

Comment: I would use state management such as NgRx. More specifically, you can use  [NgRx entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity) for CRUD. Using a state management solution will help you avoid writing generic code in each data service in your app. Also, it's much easier to debug with [Store devtools](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools)

Comment: @OZ_ thanks, could you provide more details? Maybe a link to something that shows implementation you mentioned? There is no particular reason I use Angular 15. I'm not ready to use Signals though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few changes that I think would simplify the code:

- Use plain `Subject` for actions instead of `BehaviorSubject`

  - There's no need for the initial value behavior
- Keep action subject private since it's an internal concern
- Instead of `merge`, begin your stream with the fetched user list, then switch to the results of the actions stream where modifications happen

  - IMO this more clearly conveys the relationship between the fetched list and the actions since the list is used first, then actions are applied

```js
private action$ = new Subject<ActionAdd|ActionDelete>();

users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
  switchMap(initialUsersList => this.action$.pipe(
    scan((users, action) => {
      if (action.type === 'add') {
        return users.concat(action.user);
      }
      if (action.type === 'delete') {
        return users.filter(user => user.id !== action.id);
      }
    }, initialUsersList),
    startWith(initialUsersList),
    shareReplay(1),
  )),
);
```

Notice the use of `startWith()` to initially emit the fetched list.  We also initialize the scan state with the `initialUsersList` rather than an empty array.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78010188?devtoolsHeight=35&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts) demo.

---

If you wanted to, you could extract the state updating logic into its own pure function to improve readability:

```js
users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
  switchMap(initialUsersList => this.action$.pipe(
    scan(usersListReducer, initialUsersList),
    startWith(initialUsersList),
    shareReplay(1)
  )),
);
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78010188-refactor?devtoolsHeight=35&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts) demo.

Comment: This is soo cool, thanks! I need to wrap my head around it now.

Comment: hopefully the stackblitz examples help with that.  But always feel free to ask more questions :-)